# Calling parent method dynamically from base fails with inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I am trying to dynamically call a method on my parent from my base class via `(this as dynamic).When(e)` but i am getting an error regarding protection level:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Core.dll

Additional information: 'Person.When(PersonCreated)' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

The `Person` class is public, and changing the `Person.When(PersonCreated)` to public gives a new error `The best overloaded method match for 'Person.When(PersonCreated)' has some invalid arguments`...

What I want to achieve is to 'route' events to the parent class's `When(e)` methods via the base `Apply(e)` method.

Ideally the `When` method in the base should not be public.

I'm pulling my hair out no doubt doing something very stupid... any ideas please or do I need to use reflection instead?

```
public abstract class EventSourcedAggregate
{
    readonly List<DomainEvent> mutatingEvents = new List<DomainEvent>();
    public readonly int UnmutatedVersion;

    protected void Apply(DomainEvent e)
    {
        this.mutatingEvents.Add(e);

        // the below line throws inaccessible protection level
        (this as dynamic).When(e);
    }
}

public abstract class DomainEvent
{
    // snipped some time stamp stuff not relevant here
}

public class PersonCreated : DomainEvent
{
    public readonly string Name;
    public readonly string Address;

    public PersonCreated(string name, string address)
    {
        Name = name;
        Address = address;
    }
}

public class Person : EventSourcedAggregate
{
    public Person(string name, string address)
    {
        Apply(new PersonCreated(name, address));
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Address { get; private set; }

    void When(PersonCreated e)
    {
        Name = e.Name;
        Address = e.Address;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var user = new Person("sir button", "abc street");
}
```

Comment: I get a different error after making it public. You should look at the error: `The best overloaded method match for 'UserQuery.Person.When(UserQuery.PersonCreated)' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: Is there a reason you're casting as dynamic and invoking the method? Why not just make `When` an abstract method and leverage templates?

Comment: Would that work for where i have more than 1 overloaded each with a different parameter `When` i.e. `void When(PersonCreated e)` and `When(PersonMoved e)` and `When(PersonMarried e)` etc? I am currently using this to dispatch (and it works) but would love a compile safe way! var `dispatchTo = o.GetType().GetMethod("When", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new[] { e.GetType() }, null); dispatchTo.Invoke(o, new object[] { e });`

Comment: @g18c There is a compile-safe way, but you'll need to give the compiler a bit more of a hint. For example, instead of `Apply(personCreated)`, you'll need to write `Apply(personCreated, When);`, which will correctly target the When methods you require. An example is here: http://pastebin.com/XQBghTfm . It's a bit not-nice to have to pass the Where argument each time, but this makes it type safe, and will probably optimize better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you get a different exception when the `When()` method is made `public`. I.e. it's now accessible, but you are not passing the correct type.

The `When()` method as declared *requires* an instance of `PersonCreated`. But your call site is only passing an instance of `DomainEvent`.

In general, `dynamic` defers to runtime behaviors that would normally be done at compile time. But otherwise, you have to follow the same rules. Since the compiler can't guarantee that `DomainEvent` is an instance of `PersonCreated`, you get the error (or more specifically, `DomainEvent` doesn't match a known overload of the method).

You should be able to get the code to work by calling like this instead:

```
(this as dynamic).When(e as dynamic);
```

I.e. let the runtime bind based on the dynamic type of `e` instead of its static type.

Comment: Thank you so much, 2am here and pulling hair out. That does indeed work - so the inner workings of the class can be protected, is it possible to call `When()` in the parent without making it public? Or do I need to dispatch with reflection to call internal methods?

Comment: No, `protected` won't work either. You can get away with `internal`, but it's not clear whether that sufficiently protects the member. In general, it's my opinion that you should avoid use of reflection and `dynamic` altogether. This looks like an issue better-solved via interfaces or even casting. `dynamic` is a good fallback when you have no way to control implementation of abstractions (e.g. COM interop, which is the primary reason `dynamic` exists in the first place), but typically you would, and IMHO should here.